# update samba on ubuntu 8.04ltr

Tags: ubuntu, updates, samba

I have had a few problems getting windows 7 pc's to join my samba domain.

The reason I've gathered is because the samba server software is outdated.

What is involved in updating to the newest 3.5.x from the version that comes with 8.04ltr

are there any pitfalls i should know about. 
what about very detailed instructions (I'm still learning Linux in general)

Comment: you're pretty much stuck with compiling from source; not even the latest Ubuntu beta (10.04) includes samba v3.5, or else you could just grab the source package from there and rebuild it for 8.04 (meaning easier package management).  can you get by with v3.4.7 (current in 10.04) or v3.4.0 (current in 9.10)?  can you attack the problem a different way, by reconfiguring the Win-7 pc's as in this question: http://superuser.com/questions/85719/ubuntu-samba-server-not-discovered-by-windows-7 ?

Comment: I tried the fix described in 85719 and had no luck.

I am disappointed in MS windows for not offering a clear backwards compatibility fix

Answer (score 0):

This is really better suited for Server Fault, but you have two options: upgrade to 10.04 LTS (which I'm having some fun with), or [compile Samba from source](http://www.jeremycole.com/blog/2009/12/01/upgrade-samba-3-0-28a-to-3-4-3-on-ubuntu-8-04-lts/).