# Samba Server is not discovered by Windows 7 and 8.1

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8.1, centos, samba

I set Up Samba Server on CentOS 7 inside vmware workstation. The host OS is Windows 10. Windows 7 and 8.1 cannot find the Samba Server, but I still can connect to the server using `\\server\share`.

I tried the solution from this page [Ubuntu Samba server not discovered by Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/400550/173513) but still doesn't work.

This is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = FileShareSamba
security = user
map to guest = bad user
wins support = yes
local master = yes
preferred master = yes
dns proxy = no
ntlm auth = no
lanman auth = no

#=================== Share Definitions ====================
[Anonymous]
path = /samba/anonymous
browsable =yes  
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happen when netbios has different name with machine name, so i change my machine name to `FileShareSamba` as well, now windows 7 & 8.1 can discover the samba server.

Comment: Another way to do this would be ensuring the server, all clients, and the router are all using the same local domain.  In Windows, the local domain is the WorkGroup name, whereas in all non-Windows OSes, a local domain can be specified.